# Headless Chromium on ARM Docker - Segfault

Tags: docker, arm, puppeteer, chromium, arm64

I own an instance at Oracle Cloud that is running on ARM64 platform.
I try to run the headless Chrome Docker instance, but it always fails.

What did I do:

1. Built a docker image
2. Wrote a small JS snippet that uses the Puppeteer to make screenshots
3. Ran all the things together against `https://example.com` in order to get the screenshot.

What goes wrong:
Every time, when the code tries to launch the headless version of Chrome, it fails. Either with an explicit "Segmentation fault" or with more sophisticated "Received signal 11 SEGV_ACCERR 0041b4601000".

**Looks like, no version of Chrome/Chromium that is ready to be launched on ARM64 platform exists.**

What I tried:

- Alpine Linux from scratch
- Alpine Linux with preinstall NodeJS environment
- Ubuntu Linux
- Ubuntu Linux with the installation through `dpkg -i`

The question:

**Do you know a way to run the headless Chrome/Chromium inside of an ARM64-based docker instance?**

Comment: Hi, did you resolve the issue ?

Comment: @Maxdola no. I abandoned the headless chrome idea. I needed to make screenshots of the HTML page, so I picked https://wkhtmltopdf.org. This is something similar, and it works in ARM.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I can tell you that the Oracle servers are the Problem, because I was able to run the Code on my M1 Pro MacBook which is ARM without any problems...